# Request to API with nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, api, nested, postman

I need to make a POST request to a WebAPI with a nested JSON body.
Unfortunately, I'm inexperienced in accessing WebAPIs and don't know how to do it (or how to find out if the WebAPI supports this to begin with).

I need to send a request with nested JSON because the WebAPI by default would deliver all entities, independent of which user/access token is provided. Instead the response must be limited to those entities that are linked to the logged-in user via id.

It would be much better if the backend decided which entities to deliver. But I do not have any control over the way the backend works.

---

Let's say the endpoint is webapi/something/getLst.

(Non-nested) requests with just access token work well.

### Getting all entities

#### Request:

- header: Content-Type: application/json
- body:

```
{
    "login": {
       (a handful of properties)
    }
}
```

- Auth: Bearer Token
- Method: POST

#### Response:

```
{
    "type": "tpSomethingLst",
    "login": {

    },
    "TpSomethingLstItem": [
        {
            "login": {

            },
            "id": 111
        },
        {
            "login": {

            },
            "id": 333
        }
    ]
}
```

tpSomethingLstItem is an array containing property "id" which I need to use in the request.

### Trying to get filtered list of entities

When I try to send the following request, the response is identical to a request without the nested property (i.e. the response contains all entities).

### Request

```
{
    "login": {

    }, "TpSomethingLstItem": [{"id": 111}]
}
```

It looks like this is the default behaviour for all properties that the WebAPI doesn't recognize as search properties.

---

My question is how do I request only those entities with id=111?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: There's no way for anybody to know how to answer your question. Unless I'm missing something, you just haven't given enough information. Every api is different.

Comment: Do you have any kind of filtering logic on your backend ?

Comment: I thought that the question might be agnostic to the WebAPI being used. Sorry for not including further information. However, I just found out that this WebAPI just ignores the nesting. I.E. I can request the nested property like I would any non-nested with this body: `{"login": {}, "id": 111}`